# Hyperlink inside a WinForms Label

Tags: c#, winforms, label

For example, the About dialogue of Notepad has only "Microsoft Software Licence Terms" as a hyperlink but the rest of the text is not. How can I achieve similar result with the Label (or Labels) of WinForms?

I can use two labels, one Label and another LinkLabel, but then the two will not be concatenated naturally (the width of labels may vary by the system font face or the language).

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a label. I think you will have to use a Rich Text Box and make it non-editable.

Comment: Also, you can change the background color and hide the border.

Comment: and you cannot expect everything of windows UI to be available in Winforms, if you use WPF, it is much easier.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a `LinkLabel`, then set the `LinkArea` property. This should highlight the link you want and will also be the only clickable part.

Properties > LinkArea > ... button then just highlight the text part you want as a link

Comment: I've never used a link label. Good to know,

Comment: Yeah it gets overlooked cause of how most newbie devs(like me) only see mostly used property parts when handling winforms.